# Jquery radio button repetition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="2" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>A . 1</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="2" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>B. 2</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="3" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>C. 3</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="4" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>D. 4</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="5" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>E. 5</span></div>
```

Here is my javascript code

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    alert("You checked it");
});
```

every time I checked one of this radio button, I got 6 alert boxes instead of 1 alert. What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: It's working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/vgtes9fc/

Comment: I use this $('.checkradios').checkradios() first.. And then it goes to 6 alert. If I omit it, It will be fine. Checradios is a plugin from jquery to make a beautiful radio button.

Comment: It seems `$('.checkradios').checkradios(); ` does a check event in all the radio elements. It is needless in this place. Just remove it

Comment: But I need that plugin to make my radio button more beautiful. Is there any suggestion ?

Comment: @ZainabSafiyyahAl-habsyi  you can add a CSS style to make it look better..

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you are doing this in a loop which is being iterated 6 times. Which binds the handlers 6 times on each element. Just remove your code from loop and everything will fall in place.

```
someloop{


}
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
  alert("You checked it");
});
```

Comment: @ZainabSafiyyahAl-habsyi: can you share the snippet that calls `$('.checkradios').checkradios()`

Comment: I use this $('.checkradios').checkradios() first.. And then it goes to 6 alert. If I omit it, It will be fine. Checradios is a plugin from jquery to make a beautiful radio button. How to deal with it ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('.checkradios').checkradios();

     $('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
      alert("you checked it");
     });

     $("input[type='submit']").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.box').each(function(){
       if($(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 0){
       }else{
          $(this).find('.question').attr('style','background-color:#FF0000;');
       }    
      });
     });

 });
</script>

Comment: @ZainabSafiyyahAl-habsyi: call `$('.checkradios').checkradios(); ` after `$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){ alert("you checked it"); });`

Answer (score 1):

It seems `$('.checkradios').checkradios();` does a check event in all the radio elements. It is needless in this place. Just remove it. Your code works fine without that as below

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
    alert("You checked it");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="2" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>A . 1</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="2" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>B. 2</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="3" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>C. 3</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="4" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>D. 4</span></div>
<div class="boxanswer"><input type="radio" name="idquestion[2]" value="5" class="checkradios"><span class='answer_choice'>E. 5</span></div>
```